# How to enable Document preview in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to enable Document preview of document library in  sharepoint  2013 on mouse hover. How to enable it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect your SharePoint environment with office web app server. Then use search web parts to show the documents from your document library.